# Tensorflow make Training Testing dataset from images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset

I am making an image classifier I downloaded images of 2 classes to 2 folders:

```
├── Demo
│   ├── pizza
│   |── lasagnia
```

How can I make a training and testing dataset of images in tensorflow by shuffling the images and spliting into training and testing sets.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:
`tf.split_v(tf.shuffle(images, ...), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the working directory to the folder with the 1st class:

First you will need to download the library `split-folders` (`pip install split-folders`)

```
import os
import split_folders

cwd = os.getcwd()  

split_folders.ratio(cwd, output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .2))
```

Repeat for the other class folders.